# ARKit and 3D Object / Image Recognition

Tags: ios, opencv, 3d, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm actually trying to build an app on iOS that uses augmented reality and 3D object recognition to create an animation around a specific flower pot.

I choose **ARKit** for its accuracy but it seems that only plane recognition is available.
Is someone know a SDK that can be use **with** ARKit and allows image or 3D object recognition ?

I heard about **Vision** that can detect faces and **OpenCV** but I don't know if they can do the job or if they can work simultaneously with ARKit.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Probably you would need to train your own model to detect that flower pot.

Comment: And what can I use to train my own model ?

Comment: OpenCV provides support for Haar Cascades

Comment: Well thanks for the advice ! Do you know if it's compatible with ARkit and if i can use haar cascades detection with an ARScene ?

Comment: You would need to include OpenCV for using Haar Cascades in your project, and it will work on any given image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARKit and OpenCV can combine together if that`s what your concern.

I don`t know if you have experience in developing OpenCV, if you do, then I suggest you to start working on integrating them, otherwise, you should use Vision directly.

I think OpenCV requires more background knowledge and experience.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation ! That's what I needed to know !
Actually i find OpenCV very interesting but quite complex for a beginner like me. I'm working on that project for 2 months do you think I will have enough time to make 3D object detection with OpenCV ?
And are you sure that Vision allows 3D detection ? Or at least a detection of a curved image ?

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly about your background experience of computer vision and programming skill, however I do think if you work hard, you can manage it. I think Vision with CoreML can do what you want, you should take a look at both of them. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I am late to answer this. But I think it will help other developers. From iOS 11 onwards, Apple has introduced CoreML/Vision framework. Fantastic ML based tool to do exactly what you need. This link will be helpful to achieve this - https://dev.to/osterbergjordan/arkit--vision-an-intriguing-combination

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go a little higher level you could develop your app in Unity for iOS - it supports ARKit now, and you can plug in image recognition libraries like Vuforia (easy but pricey, 1c per recognition which adds up if your app is popular) or ARtoolkit (harder but free).